Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected - could not connect to kafka container
I have been trying to get my dockerized services up, however I am facing some issues with connecting to kafka broker (docker-container) from java applications.
I am trying it on Windows, and Ubuntu.
So my docker-compose.yml is as below:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
    - “2181:2181”
    networks:
    - kafka-network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    ports:
    - “9092:9092”
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    networks:
    - kafka-network
    volumes:
    - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data # New volume for Kafka data
    - kafka-streams-state:/var/lib/kafka/streams # New volume for Kafka Streams state

  job-jays-api:
    build:
    context: …/
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: job-jays-api
    ports:
    - “8080:8080”
    networks:
    - kafka-network
  applicant-job-matcher:
    build:
    context: …/applicant_job_matcher
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: applicant-job-matcher
    depends_on:
    - job-jays-api
    networks:
    - kafka-network
  preference-updater:
    build:
    context: …/preference_updater
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: preference-updater
    depends_on:
    - job-jays-api
    networks:
    - kafka-network
  notification-sender:
    build:
    context: …/notification_sender
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: notification-sender
    depends_on:
    - job-jays-api
    networks:
    - kafka-network

networks:
  kafka-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  kafka-data:
    kafka-streams-state:

What I have tried: setting bootstrap server to kafka, localhost, ip address of the machine - non of them worked.
I was able to connect to kafka broker from the java (spring boot) app when I had the broker installed on Ubuntu OS and the spring boot app was build and ran not as containerized.

Most probably you have to review your docker compose KAFKA_LISTENERS and KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS variables. Have a look here: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

As you are usikng docker you cannot connect to localhost:9092 you need to override the bootstrap server for the application to be kafka:9092. On a differnt note I tried to format your YAML and surround it with proper code tags. Please take care of this next time when posting a question as what you had was unreadable.
